# How do I also export result returned from my search query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in my asp.net web application. I want to export records on this gridview to excel. It works perfectly when I export all the records to excel.

The issue I'm having now is that, I have a dropdown list (to search from names inside the gridview), textbox and a submit button just about the gridview. I populated the gridview based on the result returned from the database.

I also want to export this records to excel. each time I click do the search and click my "export to excel" button, all the records saved into my db are exported. I only want the records returned from my search button to be exported also.

**What I have tried:**

Here is my code for exporting to excel. Like I said, it words perfectly when I want to export all the records on the gridview to excel

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
{

Response.Clear();

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

string FileName = "Example" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
StringWriter writter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(writter);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,filename" + FileName);
GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

search.BindData();
GridView1.DataSource = search.table;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(html);
Response.Write(writter.ToString());
Response.End();
}
protected void Bexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ExportGridToExcel();
}
```

How do I modify this to also export records returned from my search query?

Comment: Need some clarification.  So your GV is initially populated with all records from a db query, then you want to filter that down based on an additional search against those records only displayed in the GV?

Comment: Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting.

Exactly. One page load, the Gv is populated and I am able to export the records to excel. What I want to achieve is to also be able to export the filtered result also to excel. After I filter I my GV is populated and I click on the "export to excel" button, I get all the records from the db being excepted again. I don't want that. I only want the current records on the Gv to be exported 

I hope I have been able to add more clarifications. Thanks a lot in ad

Comment: Are the results filtered only on the client side?  Meaning you don't post back to the server with new search criteria.

Comment: Here is what I did. The GV is inside an update panel. When the search button for filtering the fired(the search button and text for for searching are also in an update panel), the update panel of the Gv is refreshed alone, So the search criteria don't really post back the whole page to the server. Only the GV section is posted back.

Comment: I think the problem is you're re-binding the GV to the data again, instead of exporting what's in the GV after the search filter.  So either rebind from the database with a query that includes the search filter or try to export only the data in the GV - see also: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx